How to use Key Vault in a secure manner
Introduction
I am working with Azure Storage Mover to migrate on prem data from a file server to a Storage Account share.
To enable Storage Mover to access the file server on prem via SMB a Key Vault is needed to provide username and password for Storage Mover job.
Key Vault configuration
Key Vaults provide two possible ways to be connected to - via public access ("Firewalls and virtual networks" in "Networking") and via Private Endpoint ("Private endpoint connections" in "Networking"). Public access can be limited to selected vnets.
In an attempt to make the setup as secure as possible I created a private endpoint and placed it into the same vnet as the destination Storage Account.
On "Firewalls and virtual networks" I selected "allow public access from specific virtual networks and IP addresses" and selected all available Azure vnets and my public IP.
The issue
When running the Azure Storage Mover job it fails with error code "AZSM1028" which indicates problems with access to the Key Vault.
Changing Key Vault Networking settings to "Allow public access from all networks" solves this issue and the job runs as intended.
How to set up Key Vault with Storage Mover in a secure way?
My configuration works but lets me behind with concerns about security. The private endpoint seems to be useless. But public access cannot be limited as well as it seems.
Can anyone explain how to set this up in a working but as secure as possible way?

You’ve already created a private endpoint for your Key Vault. Ensure that DNS queries for the Key Vault are being resolved to the private IP address associated with the private endpoint. Verify that the private DNS zone is correctly linked and that DNS records are resolving properly

To set up your key vault securely for use with Azure Storage Mover while maintaining strong security, instead of embedding credentials directly into Key Vault, you can use Service Principal.
Create your storage account
az storage account create \
    --name arkostorageaccount1 \
    --resource-group arkorg \
    --location eastus \
    --sku Standard_LRS \
    --kind StorageV2 \
    --enable-hierarchical-namespace true


and your key vault

Add secrets for SMB access which will later be accessed by the Storage Mover.

Create the Private Endpoint for the key vault

Configure DNS for the Private Endpoint

Create and link the DNS zone with your Virtual Network


Then goto your key vault networking and disable public access and enable your private endpoint

Create your Azure Storage Mover
az storage-mover create \
    --name arkoStorageMover \
    --resource-group arkorg \
    --location eastus


create a Service Principal that can authenticate with Azure and use it to access Azure Key Vault and Storage resources.
az ad sp create-for-rbac --name "arkoStorageMoverSP" --role contributor --scopes /subscriptions/abcd-efgh-ijk-lmnop-9d23dbddfc7d/resourceGroups/arkorg


Make note of this appId and password, as you will need them later to authenticate the Storage Mover.
Grant the Service Principal Access to Key Vault
az role assignment create \
    --role "Key Vault Secrets User" \
    --assignee <appId> \
    --scope /subscriptions/abcd-efg-hijk-lmnop-9d23dbddfc7d/resourceGroups/arkorg/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/arkoKeyVault


Use this Service Principal credential in Storage Mover. This should ensure that your Key Vault remains secure while allowing Storage Mover to access it via the private endpoint.
